# How to save html div as image?

Tags: html, svg

I have render SVG image inside an DIV, now in button click i need to save that DIV as an image, image should be same as what we see in the screen.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay it's pretty simple :
first you have to make this function  `DownloadImage` that saves images to your pc and only takes the url of the image and the name to be saved to

```
DownloadImage= function(picname, dirpath) {

// This method downloads the slide at the specified resolution.


var newwindow;

obj = dirpath+picname

newWindow = window.open( obj, "SaveImage",
"directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,top=100000,left=100000,width=0,height=0 ");
newWindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true);
newWindow.close();
return false;
}
```

the next step is from Javascript code you have to select the `Div DOM OBJECT` Required and Get the `Src attribute` and pass it to the function above

Comment: This won't work, if there even exists a `src` attribute it will be referencing the svg document and not an image.